# Match_Recognize in Snowflake is not returning what I think it should

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, match-recognize

I'm sure I'm not understanding this, but this is defined as

> PATTERN: Specifying the Pattern to Match PATTERN (  ) The
> pattern defines a valid sequence of rows that represents a match. The
> pattern is defined like a regular expression (regex) and is built from
> symbols, operators, and quantifiers.

An example was:

> For example, suppose that symbol S1 is defined as stock_price < 55,
> and symbol S2 is defined as stock price > 55. The following pattern
> specifies a sequence of rows in which the stock price increased from
> less than 55 to greater than 55:

PATTERN (S1 S2)

So if I do

```
create or replace table names (id int, name varchar (500), groupid int); 

insert into names
           select 1, 'andrew', 1
           union
           select 2, 'andrew2', 1
           union
           select 3, '3andrew', 1
```

And then I do

```
select * from names
match_recognize(
partition by groupid order by id
measures
  classifier() as "classifier"
  all rows per match  
pattern (test test2)  
define test as startswith(name, 'and'),
  test2 as endswith(name, 'rew') 
 ) t
;
```

Why do I not get 'andrew' as a record return? If I put either test in the pattern, it does show it. When I put both in, it does not. Instead it is showing 3andrew and andrew2 as the record result which is unexpected for me because the example lead me to believe it works like an AND. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i'll make the edit to add this in, it doesn't change the output in this current situation however

Answer (score 2):

The pattern is `(test test2)` which means find **exactly one** row starting with `And` **followed by exactly one** that has `rew` suffix. **The pattern window has size 2.**

The rows are processed as follow:

```
1 andrew
2 andrew2
3 3andrew
```

Pass 1:

```
1 andrew
2 andrew2  -- fails it is not test2
```

Pass 2(row 1 was skipped at this point):

```
2 andrew2   -- test  pass
3 3andrew   -- test2 pass
```

Return rows 2 and 3 and start the search process again(if they are still rows to process).

If you want arbitrary number of test, then pattern should be `(test+ test2)` - (window size is at least 2).

If you want element to be one of the two then pattern should be `(test|test2)` - (window size is 1).

---

Recommended reading: [match_recognize — Regular Expressions Over Rows](https://modern-sql.com/feature/match_recognize)

Answer (score 0):

so your pattern `pattern (test test2)` as I understand it is say find a row where `test` passes and latter row where `test2` passes.

[MATCH_RECOGNIZE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/match_recognize.html) says of the operator   (space) which you have between your two rules:

> Concatenation. Specifies that a symbol or operation should follow another one. For example, S1 S2 means that the condition defined for S2 should occur after the condition defined for S1.

But I suspect your question is why does row id 1 not match on `test` and then row 3 match on `test2`.. and I believe it is the `AFTER MATCH SKIP` the defaults to `PAST LAST ROW` which find row 1 & 2 match test, so it starts after the last, thus you only get one match. Not that I could use that section to turn off this behavior.

If I change the input data a little:

```
WITH names(id, name, groupid) as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        (10, 'andrew', 1),
        (20, '2andrew', 1),
        (30, 'andrew3', 1),
        (40, 'simeon', 1),
        (50, '4andrew', 1)
)
```

this gives:

```
ID  NAME    GROUPID classifier
10  andrew  1   TEST
20  2andrew 1   TEST2
```

So row 10 can work, but it seems in your data 2 binds closer to 3, but in my data 30 does not match 50. Also of note is you have no order by clause in you match, which means you might get non-deterministic results. Unless you have re-sorted you data elsewhere..

thus change adding a `partition` and `order` clause means both andrews now trigger:

```
WITH names(id, name, groupid) as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        (10, 'andrew', 1),
        (11, 'simeon', 2),
        (20, '2andrew', 1),
        (30, 'andrew3', 1),
        (60, 'simeon', 1),
        (50, '4andrew', 1)
)           
select * 
from names
match_recognize(
  partition by groupid 
  order by id
  measures
    classifier() as "classifier"
    all rows per match  

  pattern (test test2)  
  define test as startswith(name, 'and'),
    test2 as endswith(name, 'rew') 
 ) t
;
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still confused with AFTER MATCH SKIP the defaults to PAST LAST ROW
In my original example (post edit), 

for 'test': andrew matches, so that's one and it runs to the next sequential one which is andrew2 and returns andrew2.
for test2: i do not understand how this gets '3andrew'... what exactly are the steps I'm supposed to interpret to get to that as the result?